# Python bytes decode parsing windows directory as an escape sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, unicode, escaping

I'm working with a byte string in the format:
`b'directory\file'`

I'm trying to convert this byte string to an ASCII string (as I know 100% that all characters will be within the character set) but if the file name begins with the letter x, python will try to decode the next two bytes as a hexadecimal character, leading to a 'UnicodeDecodeError' exception.

I also do not have control of the source as it is read from a tcp socket so I cannot add an escape character at the source.

How do I decode the bytes literally, ignoring the escape sequence?

An example of a byte string that would cause this exception would be:
`b'dir\xfile'`

Ignoring the errors or using the unicode_escape codec will just result in the 4 character (\x and the next two) being removed - not the desired result.

A cheap solution I could do is catch the exception and regex for the characters it tries to parse as hex from the exception message and handle their conversion myself, but that seems like an incredibly inefficient and hacky solution.

A minimal re-producible example:

```
var = b'var_\xbFEHDBJINDHBSGFWHSBWHBDFT'
var.decode('ascii')
```

But it is important to remember that var comes from a TCP socket receive, so it is dynamic and not hard-coded into the python file.

Comment: `br'directory\file'`?

Comment: Is it possible to do that to a variable? I'm using socket.recv to receive my data and don't input it manually.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `br'dir\xfile'.decode('ascii')` works fine and will never decode a backslash and an x as a hexadecimal string.  Only a literal source string such as `b'dir\xfile'` will try to do that, and that is a `SyntaxError`.  The bytes you receive from a TCP socket will never do that.

Comment: @JosefZ I have edited the question to provide a minimal reproducible example. I am unable to include an example of the TCP receive as you would not have access to the system that is outputting the data.

Comment: @MarkTolonen as described above, I am unable to hardcode br into the program as the data is received via a TCP socket and not hardcoded into the python.

Comment: Please share `repr(whatever_you_receive_from_tcp_socket)`. You could try [`var.decode('raw_unicode_escape')` or `var.decode('unicode_escape')`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#text-encodings).

Comment: @JosefZ raw_unicode_escape is the correct answer and solves the problem, thank you. If you would like to add it as an answer I will mark it as the correct solution.

Comment: `br''` is **only** for literal strings typed into source code just like you used `b''` to make your example.  It prevents a literal string such as `b'\xbf'` to be interpreted as a single byte of value 0xBF and makes a 4-byte string instead `br'\xbf'` with a backslash and `xbf`.  `raw_unicode_escape` does *nothing* to your example string.  For a string received from a tcp socket, just `.decode('ascii')`.  Do what @JosefZ said and `print(repr(whatever_you_receive))`.  Show us an *actual example* of `.decode('ascii')` giving you a UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: Note that to have a `\xbf` in your example string, the tcp socket *sent a single byte of value 0xBF*.  If that is the case you have an XY problem and the real problem is sending non-ASCII bytes in the first place.  `b'\xbf'.decode('raw_unicode_escape')` gives `'¿'` as an answer because U+00BF is the Unicode code point for `¿` and that encoding allows for non-ASCII (specfically, `latin1`) characters.  You still aren't getting your `dir\file` required result leaving the backslash in the string.